# Monitoring instances in cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring

I usually use Munin as monitoring software, but this (as others software I presume) needs an IP to make the ICMP or whatever pings to collect data.

In Amazon EC2 instances are created on the fly, with IP's you don't know.

How can they be monitored ?

I was thinking about using amazon console commands to read the IP's of the instances up, and change the monit configuration file on the fly also , but it can be too complicated ... or not?

Any other solution / suggestion ?

Thank you

Comment: Presumably at least one other box in your system knows where the newly-created machine is, or nothing would be able to make use of it? What sort of monitoring do you want to do, and will Amazon CloudWatch do what you need?

Answer (score 2):

I use [revealcloud](http://www.copperegg.com/product/revealcloud/) to monitor my amazon instances.  You can install it once and create an ami from that systen, or bootstrap the install command if that's your method.  Since the install is just one command, it's easy enough to put into the rc.local (or similar).  You can then see all the instances in the dashboard or topiew as soon as they boot up.

Answer (score 0):

Our instances are bootstrapped using chef recipes, so it's easier for me to provide IPs/hosts as they (= all members of my cluster) get entered into `/etc/hosts` on start-up. Generally, it doesn't hurt to use elastic IPs for a master server and allow all connections (in `/etc/munin/munin.conf` by default).

I'd solve the security 'question' on the security groups level. E.g. allow only instances with a certain security group to connect to the munin-node process (on port `4949`). The question which remains is.

E.g., using `ec2-authorize` you can achieve

```
ec2-authorize mygroup -o monitorgroup -u <AWS-USER-ID>
```

This means that all instances with group `monitorgroup` can access resources on instances with `mygroup`.

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your Munin master and nodes are all hosted on EC2 than it's better to use internal hosts like domU-00-00-00-00-00-00.compute-1.internal. because this way you don't have to deal with IP addresses and security groups.

You also have to set this in /etc/munin/munin-node.conf:

```
allow ^.*$
```

You can read more about it in [Monitoring AWS Ubuntu Instances using Munin](http://blog.augmentedfragments.com/2008/11/monitoring-aws-ubuntu-instances-using.html)

But if your Munin master is not on EC2 your best bet is to attach [Elastic IP](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3423079507145187) to your EC2 instance.